# Sequelize, check row exists and return boolean

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Please, help

How can I implement a request 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Followers WHERE follower_id = 100);' via Sequelize and display the result in a separate field?

something like this

```
await Followers.findAll({
  where: { user_id: userId },
  include: [
     {
      model: Followers,
      as: 'isSubscribed',
      ...
      },
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Something like

```
let followersCount = Followers.count({ where: {follower_id: 100} })

if(followersCount > 0){
  //EXISTS, Do Something
}
else{
   //Does not exist
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. But then it will be too many requests. I need to do a check for each row